# Protractor how to get all child elements from parent element

Tags: javascript, protractor

Hi I have following html for radio buttons. I am trying to get the list of child elements for the parent element using by.model and iterate through them and select the radio buttons. I tried the following code but it says no element found

```
var drilldownRadios = element(by.model('filterParameters.rptGrping')).$$("md-radio-button");
```

the HTML code from the app

```
<md-radio-group layout="row" ng-model="filterParameters.rptGrping" class="ng-pristine ng-valid _md layout-row ng-not-empty ng-touched" role="radiogroup" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-activedescendant="radio_2722" style="">
   <md-radio-button value="National" id="radio_2720" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-label="National">
      <div class="md-container" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox="">
         <div class="md-off"></div>
         <div class="md-on"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-transclude="" class="md-label">
         <filtertext class="ng-scope">National</filtertext>
      </div>
   </md-radio-button>
   <!-- ngIf: !$ctrl.reportInfo.authRoleClasses.studentInfo -->
   <md-radio-button ng-if="!$ctrl.reportInfo.authRoleClasses.studentInfo" ng-click="$ctrl.setSelectedStates()" class="stateRadio ng-scope md-checked" value="State" role="radio" tabindex="0" id="radio_2722" aria-checked="true" aria-label="California" style="">
      <div class="md-container" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox="">
         <div class="md-off"></div>
         <div class="md-on"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-transclude="" class="md-label">
         <filtertext class="ng-binding ng-scope">California</filtertext>
      </div>
   </md-radio-button>
   <!-- end ngIf: !$ctrl.reportInfo.authRoleClasses.studentInfo -->
   <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.reportInfo.authRoleClasses.studentInfo -->
   <!-- ngIf: !$ctrl.reportInfo.authRoleClasses.studentInfo -->
   <md-radio-button value="District" ng-click="$ctrl.setSelectedStates()" ng-if="!$ctrl.reportInfo.authRoleClasses.studentInfo" class="ng-scope" role="radio" tabindex="0" id="radio_2723" aria-checked="false" aria-label="California and District(s)" style="">
      <div class="md-container" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox="">
         <div class="md-off"></div>
         <div class="md-on"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-transclude="" class="md-label">
         <filtertext class="ng-binding ng-scope">California and District(s)</filtertext>
      </div>
   </md-radio-button>
   <!-- end ngIf: !$ctrl.reportInfo.authRoleClasses.studentInfo -->
</md-radio-group>
```

Comment: do you get a result by running `document.querySelector('[ng-model="filterParameters.rptGrping"]')` in the console of your browser?

Comment: @FlorentB. I got the result in console but it shows only html code for first two radio options, National and California when I expand the code

Comment: @Vin "District" may be missing if the `ng-if` statement is filtering it out.

Comment: @JstnPwll you are right, there are two set of elements with same parent name and child names except one change in the class ng-touched in one of the element.  using this I am able to find the element    `.ng-touched[ng-model="filterParameters.rptGrping"] md-radio-button`

Comment: but I am trying like this   `var drilldownRadios = element(by.css(".ng-touched[ng-model='filterParameters.rptGrping']")).$("md-radio-button");`  but when I run the script as 
   `drilldownRadios.count().then(function(drillcnt)` I am getting .count is not a function. Any idea how to try this. I want to find all child elements for a given parent element.

Comment: You should use `count()` on `element.all()`.  `element(by.css(".ng-touched[ng-model='filterParameters.rptGrping']")).$$("md-radio-button").count()`

Answer (score 0):

`element.all` returns an array of objects with the `modelfilterParameters.rptGrping`

`var drilldownRadios = element.all(by.model('filterParameters.rptGrping')).$$("md-radio-button");
drilldownRadios.then(function(arrayElements){
   console.log(arrayElements.length);
});`